# Ajax load instances from a has_many association

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a scenario where a `Game` has many `Achievements`. Setup as a todo app I have a form where users create a list of achievements they would like to complete. They first choose the game from and from their the achievements for that game populate below.

The challenge I'm facing is asynchronously gathering the achievements that `belong_to` that particular game. So if the user selects *Halo* then all the achievements would load from that select box's change event.

I have a general idea on writing the change event but was wondering how the ajax would be written for this to work to load the achievements.

**Models**

```
class User
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many_and_belongs_to_many :achievements
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :achievements
end

class Achievements < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
  belongs_to :game
end
```

**Task Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :game_id, as: :select, collection: @games, include_blank: "Select a game", input_html: {class: "game-select"} %>
    <%= f.input :achievement_ids, as: :select, collection: @achievements, include_blank: "Select achievements", input_html: {multiple: true, class: "achievement-select"} %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $(".game-select").on("change", function() {
    // Load and insert achievements for game into ".achievement-select" select box
  });
});
```

**Achievements Controller**

```
class AchievementsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @achievements = Achievement.all
  end

  def show
    @achievement = Achievement.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: I would have your ajax call a url like `"/achievements?game_id=123"` to get the data for all achievements with that game_id.   Obviously the `achievements#index`  action should know what to do when it gets that parameter.

Comment: How would you dynamically call the url being that `game_id=123` won't be the same for every call?

Comment: I'll do a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select options should, in their value attribute, store the game id.  Build this like

```
<% game_options = [["",""]] + Game.order("name").all.collect{|game| [game.name, game.id]} %>
<%= select_tag "game_id", options_for_select(game_options), :class => "game-select" %>
```

The game_options variable could be moved into a class method in the Game class, eg called "select_options" or something.

Now when this changes, you can read the game id out of it's value.  You could do it like so:

```
$(function() {

  $(".game-select").on("change", function() {
    if($(this).val() != ""){
      $.getJSON("/achievements", {"game_id": $(this).val()})
        .done(function(data){
          $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
            //do something with the json for this achievement
          });
        });
    }
  });

});
```

EDIT:  I made the view code use the more modern rails find syntax, and also made the javascript not do anything if the select is changed to the blank option.

EDIT2: like i said, if we want to send params[:game_id], and get back all the json data just for achievements with that game id, then the controller will need to take those params into account.  There's various ways you could do this, some dryer than others.  I'm going to do the simplest possible thing, rather than the most extensible thing.

```
#in Achievements controller
def index
  if params[:game_id]
    @achievements = Achievement.where(:game_id => params[:game_id]).all
  else
    @achievements = Achievement.all
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :action => "index"}
    format.json { render :json => @achievements.to_json }
  end
end
```

Comment: How should I interpret the `+` operator in the `options_for_select` method? I get `Couldn't find all Games with 'id': (all, {:order=>"name"}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)`

Comment: Oh, i think i used some older rails syntax which has been deprecated.  I'll do an edit.  The + is just adding two arrays together.

Comment: After the select box change event I get this in my console: `GET http://localhost:3000/achievements?game_id=1 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Earlier i said "Obviously the achievements#index action should know what to do when it gets that parameter."  What i meant by this was that there's an assumption in my answer that you have an achievements controller and that it is accessed via the standard restful routes, eg `GET "/achievements"` goes to the index action, `GET "/achievements/1"` goes to the show action with params[:id] = 1 etc.  Furthermore, the code of the achievements#index action should look to see if params[:game_id] was passed, and if so, load only the achievements with that game id.

Comment: Okay I think everything is setup as far as the necessary achievement views/controllers/routes are setup. I think the remaining issue is the JS. I'm not getting anything from the code I put inside the code block for `done()`.

Comment: Put this inside the done block:  `console.log("data = "+JSON.stringify(data));`.  This will let you see what json data you're getting back.  You can copy this into the console and play around with it.  In this sort of situation i would have the data in a text file and experiment with bits of javascript to update my page or whatever, copying from my text file into the console, and leave rails out of it (if you know you're getting the right data back).

Comment: I was thinking the same way you were as far as using `console.log` but I'm not getting any data at all. Not even an error.

Comment: Can you include (in your question, not a comment) the code for your achievements#index action?

Comment: Hey any idea on how to fix this based on my controller code?

Comment: I put an edit in my question with some suggested controller code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81539/discussion-between-carl-edwards-and-max-williams).

Comment: Still end up with nothing

Comment: Make another question, describe the current state of your code, and describe your problem in more detail please.  This has strayed too far away from your original question i think.

Comment: Not sure how I can be any more specific. What more are you looking for?

Comment: Got this error in my JS console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: It points to the jQuery source line 359: `length = obj.length`

Comment: Further down the stack trace you should see a reference to code that's actually in your app rather than a library.  What is that line?

Comment: `$.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {`

Comment: Try changing it to `$.each( data, function( i, item ) {`

Comment: Great! It seems to work now. There was one additional error I found in the js. At close of `$.each` body there needs to be `);` after the right curly brace. Once that's fixed I can mark this as correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: aha!  that's the danger of writing code from memory and not testing it :/  glad you got it working eventually!

Answer (score 0):

So ...such as we have 'simple_form_for(@task)', it is view form for Task Model.

In my opinion, You could write next in Task Model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
  has_many :achievements, through: :game
end
```

and after this in TasksController You could use:
(updated)

```
def update
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])    
  @achievements = @task.achievements
  @achievement_ids = @achievements.map { |a| [a.name, a.id] }
end
```

for use into form.

Comment: Yea! ...this Task View You should use with the TasksController insteed of the  AchievementsController...